# How to associate nonce attribute random id with inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, nonce

I'm adding Content-Security-Policy restrictions on a site. So inline JS and CSS is no longer available. But I should have a few inline JSs on every page therefore I'm adding nonce attribute.
Should I generate new random id for every inline script and css on a page

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="url/example1.js" nonce="id-1"/>
<script src="url/example2.js" nonce="id-2"/>
<script src="url/example3.js" nonce="id-3"/>
</head>
</html>
```

or I can generate one id and reuse it for every JS and CSS on the page(Is it safely like with the way above)?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="url/example1.js" nonce="id-1"/>
<script src="url/example2.js" nonce="id-1"/>
<script src="url/example3.js" nonce="id-1"/>
</head>
</html>
```

For me both approaches work good but CSP header has length limit(1024 chars). Every id looks like 'nonce-{*20..30 chars*}'. There is a risk that next new inline JS can be rejected...

Comment: `...but CSP header has length limit(1024 chars)...` - really it's not true. I use CSP header of 5036 chars length. Length CSP of `https://twitter.com/` is 2560 chars. I have met only one restriction - [LimitRequestFieldsize=8190](https://csplite.com/csp31/#htaccess502) bytes as maximum size for **all** HTTP headers in Ahache server. Also browsers for some old mobiles had limited input buffers for headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#security-nonces says that you should generate a unique value every time you submit your policy. This means that you can reuse the nonce throughout the document. On the next page load you need a new nonce.